# My location button not showing after accept location permission when using google_maps_flutter?

Tags: flutter, google-maps-flutter

i have a problem when using google maps with Flutter,

https://pub.dev/packages/google_maps_flutter

My code is as below:

```
GoogleMap(
          mapType: MapType.normal,
          myLocationEnabled: true,
          myLocationButtonEnabled: true,
          onMapCreated: _onMapCreated,
          padding: EdgeInsets.only(top: ScreenUtil().setHeight(100)),
          zoomControlsEnabled: false,
          initialCameraPosition: CameraPosition(
            target: _currentPosition ?? Constants.DEFAULT_POSITION,
            zoom: 17,
          ),
        )
```

At the first time it run, the location permission dialog shown up,
And when i accept the permission, the my location button didn't apprear.

At the second time i open the googlemap page (at this time, the permission is already granted), the my location is shown as normal.

Thanks

Comment: So what do you want exactly?

Comment: I want after granted the location permission, the my location button and the marker of my location shown as normal,

Comment: Is this on iOS?

Comment: @jabamataro I get this error on Android

Comment: are there any exact error messages you are getting?

Comment: Seeing the same issue. Current location doesn't appear after accepting permissions (no error).